# Тюнинг тулбара от ComCtl32

Tags: c, winapi

Разместил на окне тулбар средствами WinApi, задействовал для этого ComCtl32. Но стандартное размещение как-то не очень, некрасивые отступы. См. скриншот, на нем отступы обозначил стрелочками:

[image: скрин]

**Собственно вопрос:** как можно все отступы сделать равными, чтобы смотрелось красивше?